# What is the meaning of "hold himself" and "in reverse" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

He knew when to attack and when to remain upon the defensive, when to press on the enemy and when to hold himself in reserve and let the enemy follow his own devices.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: It's not 'reverse', it's 'reserve'. Do you know what to 'hold something in reserve' means?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Thank you Michael. I know It's meaning.

Comment: So is your question now answered?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, It is answered dear Michael (reserve not  reverse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hold someone or (something) in reserve means to hold them (or it) back for future needs.

> I am holding the frozen desserts in reserve, in case we run out of
> cake.